# My footer div is not showing?

Tags: html, footer

I am working on a small PSD to HTML File. So did everything and completed the whole index file somehow but now at last when I came to create the footer and nothing is showing up.

Wondering why footer is not showing?

Here is the index page link : http://www.webngraphicssolutions.com/urgent_psd/index.html

Comment: a problem in your page: **the scroll** you should change direction of your page.

Comment: although i did some editings and now the footer shows but there is too alot white space down the footer so how that can be removed now?

Comment: and how to change the direction of page for the scroll?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you have `style="position:absolute; top:150px;"` applied to the image inside the footer. And there is nothing in the footer other than that.

Do this, to see that footer image is loading but is not visible due to positioning.

```
style="position:absolute; top:50px; left:100px"
```

or do this

```
style="position:fixed; bottom:0; left:40%;"
```

You need to remove absolute positioning and let the footer fall where it should, then apply relative positioning or absolute one if required.

A comment: bad bad HTML/CSS programming.

But as an exercise,

1. first create Container, Header, Content and Footer.
2. Fill them with data. Do not apply CSS yet, get to know their static positions first.
3. Then, move things around with position and floating.

This is not how seasoned web designer work, but it's a start.

Comment: can you please now take a look at the page.i did some editings but now there is alot white space down the footer so how can be that space now removed?

Comment: and thanks.Bro..right i am a beginner web designer that's why i am facing these problems,but will succeed if you people help me to learn.

Answer (score 0):

`position:fixed;` on your css

see if it helps

Comment: although i did some editings and now the footer shows but there is too alot white space down the footer so how that can be removed now?